# How can I get property name strings used in a Func of T

Tags: c#, parameters, lambda

I have a scenario where I have to get an array of strings that represent each of the property names used within a Func parameter.  Here is an example implementation:

```
public class CustomClass<TSource>
{
  public string[] GetPropertiesUsed
  {
    get
    {
      // do magical parsing based upon parameter passed into CustomMethod
    }
  }

  public void CustomMethod(Func<TSource, object> method)
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Here would be an example usage:

```
var customClass = new CustomClass<Person>();
customClass.CustomMethod(src => "(" + src.AreaCode + ") " + src.Phone);

...

var propertiesUsed = customClass.GetPropertiesUsed;
// propertiesUsed should contain ["AreaCode", "Phone"]
```

The part I'm stuck on in the above is the *"do magical parsing based upon parameter passed into CustomMethod."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to change your CustomMethod to take an `Expression<Func<TSource, object>>`, and probably subclass the `ExpressionVisitor`, overriding `VisitMember`:

```
public void CustomMethod(Expression<Func<TSource, object>> method)
{
     PropertyFinder lister = new PropertyFinder();
     properties = lister.Parse((Expression) expr);
}

// this will be what you want to return from GetPropertiesUsed
List<string> properties;

public class PropertyFinder : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public List<string> Parse(Expression expression)
    {
        properties.Clear();
        Visit(expression);
        return properties;
    }

    List<string> properties = new List<string>();

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression m)
    {
        // look at m to see what the property name is and add it to properties
        ... code here ...
        // then return the result of ExpressionVisitor.VisitMember
        return base.VisitMember(m);
    }
}
```

This should get you started in the right direction.  Let me know if you need some help figuring out the "... code here ..." part.

Useful links:

- [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)
- [How to Modify Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx)
- [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx)
- [VisitMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.visitmember.aspx)
- [MemberExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

You should use `Expression<Func<>>` class instead. The expression contains actual tree, and can easily be complied to get a delegate (which is a func). What You are really trying to do is to look at the body of the expression and reason about it. Expression class provides You with all the neccessary infrastructure.