# Get string version of lambda expression property

Tags: linq, generics, c#-4.0, expression

**Similar to question [How can I get property name strings used in a Func of T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726565/how-can-i-get-property-name-strings-used-in-a-func-of-t).**

Let's say I had a lambda expression
stored like this in a variable called "getter"

```
Expression<Func<Customer, string>> productNameSelector =
    customer => customer.Product.Name;
```

**how can I extract the string "Product.Name" from that?**

I now fixed it somewhat haxy with

```
var expression = productNameSelector.ToString();
var token = expression.Substring(expression.IndexOf('.') + 1);
```

But i'd like to find a more solid way ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression tree for your expression looks like this:

```
           .
          / \
         .   Name
        / \
customer   Product
```

As you can see, there is no node that would represent `Product.Name`. But you can use recursion and build the string yourself:

```
public static string GetPropertyPath(LambdaExpression expression)
{
    return GetPropertyPathInternal(expression.Body);
}

private static string GetPropertyPathInternal(Expression expression)
{
    // the node represents parameter of the expression; we're ignoring it
    if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
        return null;

    // the node is a member access; use recursion to get the left part
    // and then append the right part to it
    if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
    {
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression;

        string left = GetPropertyPathInternal(memberExpression.Expression);
        string right = memberExpression.Member.Name;

        if (left == null)
            return right;

        return string.Format("{0}.{1}", left, right);
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        string.Format("Unknown expression type {0}.", expression.NodeType));
}
```

Comment: That's the kind of solution I was hoping for! Tested this in my project, and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Expression you can use the ToString method to extract the string representation:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, string>> productNameSelector = 
    customer => customer.Product.Name;

var expression = productNameSelector.ToString();
var token = expression.Substring(expression.IndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Comment: Okay yours is basically a more readable and cleaner version of what I wrote (+1), but It still seems like a crappy  workaround, or should I trust this to work in production ...:)

Comment: Which is the problem of this approach? What you don't like of it?

Comment: @MatteoMigliore I think it's quite unclear that it would always work correctly. And if you give it “weird” expression, it might produce unexpected results, instead of failing with an exception. And when it does fail with an exception, its message won't help you much.

Comment: IDK, It feels to me like this relies too much on the internal workings of .NET, if they change the ToString() function of Expression by adding something at the end in a next version of .NET it breaks.
I'll stick with it for now though thanks! I was hoping for something more like "SomeLinqHelperClass.GetFullPropertyName(getter)" but this doesn't seem to exist at first

Comment: The [library](http://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com) IQToolkit has an implementation of the visitor pattern called _ExpressionVisitor_.

Comment: @MatteoMigliore Since .Net 4.0, [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) is included in the framework. But it's not clear to me how exactly are you proposing it should be used here.

Comment: The result of a method of a type of the .NET Framework is always the same to guarantee the backward compatibility.

Comment: @svick the [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) can [extract](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726565/how-can-i-get-property-name-strings-used-in-a-func-of-t) all the property names that are into the expression.